# What is the Pros and Cons of IWS based web service Vs CGI programming in IBM i

Tags: web-services, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am new to the web serivce programming in IBM i, based on my initial reseach I found couple of ways to achieve it.

1. Using Integrated Web Service platform comes with IBM i (http://hostname:2001/HTTPAdmin) but it needs profile with *IOSYSCFG authority
2. Using just CGI programming using Apache web server and editing the httpd.conf file and using ScriptAliasMatch to route to my RPGLE

But I wanted to know, what will be the best practice and Pros and Cons of each. From myside, I am not able to explore much because I am not authorized to use a profile with *IOSYSCFG authority

I made few programs with CGI concept but need to know how efficient it is when it comes to security?

Thanks in advance for your help..!!

Answer (score 2):

I consider IWS a quick way to wrap an existing code...

But it also requires less understanding of web services.

Downside are limits on the parameter types it supports. Note: you don't need *IOSYSCFG, as somebody with *IOSYSCFG can give individual users or groups of users permission to manage IWS servers.

CGI requires a better understanding of web services...but you can still leverage your RPG skills.  It's old, but sometime is still a decent tool.

Have you considered Node.js, python, or PHP all of which are available for the i? they enable a whole world of options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your point on *IOSYSCFG helps me. Also I have already started to play around with Python but not with Node.js or PHP yet. I will look for options from that also.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a little bit late (as most of the time here ;-) ) but to give any user researching this topic another option: Why not use ILEastic (coupled with noxDB). Both projects are open source and available on github and ILE service programs. ILEastic follows the same concepts as many frameworks on other platforms and languages like Express (Node.js), Dropwizard (Java), Ninja (Java), Helidon (Java), Quarkus (Java), ....

You can find a tutorial at https://champions.rpgnextgen.com . I you have any questions just drop me a mail.